# System.out.println(); is printing two lines

Tags: java

I've recently started studying Java and I already had my first problem. Currently I'm making a text adventure game (written in Java) and I can't continue because the program is printing out two lines but that I don't want it to. I don't how I can make it print out only one line.

In the last bit of the program there is a system.out.print("hello")

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAd2 {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Name
String Pname;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //connection
    TextAd2 con;
    con = new TextAd2();

    con.info();
    con.start1();
}

public void info() {

System.out.println("Hello!");
System.out.println("Your Name? ");
Pname = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello " + Pname);
System.out.println("Wana Start The Game or Stop?");
String text1 = sc.nextLine();

    switch (text1) {
    case "Start":
        start1();
        break;

    case "Stop":
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Unknown Command.");
    }
}
public void start1()
{
    //it starts to print this twice
    System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

I actually don't think that the system.out.print is the problem, maybe the program is just reading the 'start1()' twice that's why it's printing "hello" two times. I did this in an if else statement and it's doing the same thing too. I don't know the code to how to prevent this either way. I am doing something wrong but I don't know what is the probelm

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You call `start1()` twice, once in the `info()` function and once in the main function.

Comment: That worked thank you, I thought I have to connect it to the main function for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can calling twice `con.start1();`

Once in your `main()`:

```
con.info();
con.start1();
```

And the second time in your `switch`:

```
   case "Start":
        start1();
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, the execution reaches this line:

```
con.info();
```

So `info` starts running. Then execution reached:

```
case "Start":
    start1();
    break;
```

So `start1` starts executing and prints `Hello`.

*However*, remember that the deepest call stack is still on the `info` method. After printing `Hello`, `start1` returns it is popped from the call stack. `break;` then runs and `info` also pops from the call stack. Now, we will go to the next line after `info()`, which is `start1`!

That's why it is printing twice. To stop this, simply remove `start1` from the `main` method,